# How to init spring-cloud-zookeeper-config configs

Tags: java, spring-cloud, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I have multiple spring boot applications, and I put the configs in `application-{profile}` file in project.
Now I'm trying to use zookeeper as spring cloud config center, what's the best way to migrate those configs to zookeeper please? I really don't want to add it manually since there are tons of configurations!